# MongoDB update by id (with $set) not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've been searching for an explanation on this (I'm obviously doing something wrong) with no luck so far, I have this collection on my DB:

```
db.activeCustomers.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ade8f280648c78cee70b5a"),
    "name" : "Gustavo",
    "lastName" : "Lara",
    "age" : 25,
    "hobbies" : [
        "rubik",
        "guitar",
        "games"
    ],
    "sex" : "male"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ade8f280648c78cee70b5b"),
    "name" : "Diana",
    "lastName" : "Lara",
    "age" : 23,
    "sex" : "female"
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ade8f280648c78cee70b5c"), "sex" : "female" }
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58adf5a65da705df647fcbe0"),
    "name" : "Juan",
    "lastName" : "Pérez",
    "age" : 34,
    "sex" : "male"
}
```

And I want to update the 3rd object (the one with just _id and sex) using this:

```
db.activeCustomer.update({_id: ObjectId("58ade8f280648c78cee70b5c")}, {$set: {name: "Myrna", lastName: "Guerrero", age: 26}});
```

but no data is updated, I get this:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

According to [this](https://specify.io/how-tos/mongodb-update-documents), I'm doing it right, maybe I'm doing a wrong combination of the API functionality, or it's a version thing? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm using mongo v3.4.1

Comment: Just a typo in the collection name? `db.activeCustomer` without "s" ?

Comment: ok, now I feel dumb, thanks! (and sorry for wasting server space with the question)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's just a typo in:

```
db.activeCustomer.update({...
```

it should be activeCustomer**s**